# Android AlertDialog setOnCanceledOnTouchOutside

Tags: android, android-dialog

I create `AlertDialog`, I set `setOnCanceledOnTouchOutside` and `setCancelable` params, but then I click outside dialog it hides. Maybe someone can help me?

```
dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).setView(table).setTitle(R.string.order_start_title)
.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        onOrderStartCancel(context);
    }
}).setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_start_order, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        onOrderStart(context, goodsTypeId, goodType);
    }
}).create();
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: so dont want to hide dialog ?

Comment: yes, the dialog must hide after button click.

Comment: at least read the documentation of the methods you are using ...

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want to allow user to cancel dialog then

use

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);
                     ^^^^^
```

instead of

```
dialog.setCancelable(true);
```

also remove this `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true); <---`
if not needed.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);
```